# Best fit time scheduling algorithm for event management application

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, scheduling, genetic-algorithm

Im working on a Real world Event Management applicationwhere Events are scheduled based on availability of venue place, none of the events should clash.
     What is the best possibility to insert the next value.

Example:
Suppose Event1 is happening between 9 and 9:30 at Room A
Event2 is happening between 9 and 10:00 at Room B
Event3 can start at 9:30 at Room A since its free after 9:30 n so on......

Which algorithm can I use?

Note: This is not CPU scheduling algorithm

Thanks :)

Comment: What other characteristics do you want the algorithm to have? Do you want to minimize fragmentation, in case long events come up?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with greedy approach.

1. Sort all the events according to start time
2. For each venue:

   1. T=earliest time
   2. Find the earliest event at or after T and schedule it for this venue. Remove that event from the list.
   3. Update T to end time of this event

Once this is completed you can use some kind of local search (simulated annealing based) to further optimize the assignment.

Comment: Yep, start with [First Fit Decreasing](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta2/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3671), then [Tabu Search or Simulated Annealing](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta2/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3817).